# Getting current Application context in constructor, not in PostConstruct?

Tags: spring, c3p0

So I have a DAO with some datasources that might change. I tried autowiring the C3P0 datasources and setting them in the PostCostruct, but for some reason if I do that I get some connection errors. I still don't understand why, but if I change the datasources in the Postconstruct they stop working, even though everything looks ok.

I'm trying to get the applicationContext from the constructor, so I can do something like this:

```
ApplicationContextProvider.getContext().getBean("myDataSource", DataSource.class);
```

This is my ApplicationContextProvider class:

```
@Component
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements 
ApplicationContextAware
{
   private static ApplicationContext context;

   @Override
   public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException
   {
      context = applicationContext;
   }

   public static ApplicationContext getContext() {
      return context;
   }

}
```

This is pretty much the DAO I'm working with:

```
@Component
public abstract class myDao{

    private DataSource myDataSource;

    protected myDao(){
        dataSourceToUse = ApplicationContextProvider.getContext().getBean("dataSourceId", DataSource.class);
    }
```

When I run that, the context is null. How do I get it? Am I missing something?